# NullPointerException in BouncyCastleProvider while creating X509Certificate

Tags: java, certificate, x509certificate, bouncycastle

I'm creating `X509Certificate` from bytes, but that is throwing `NullPointerException`, In my application I'm doing two way(Step one getting Signature data in Bytes stored into DB, later i fetched from DB), both are consolidate in one shot, Getting exception in last line(`System.out.println`)

```
public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
    File file = new File("C://connect.cer");
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) certFactory.generateCertificate(input);
    byte[] certBytes = cert.getSignature();
    System.out.println("IssuerDN Name>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+cert.getIssuerDN().getName()+">>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
    InputStream input2 = new ByteArrayInputStream(certBytes);
    CertificateFactory certFactory2 = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509", "BC");
    X509Certificate cert2 = (X509Certificate) certFactory2.generateCertificate(input2); 
    System.out.println("IssuerDN Name>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+cert2.getIssuerDN().getName()+">>>>>>>>>>>>>>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of  `cert.getSignature()` i used `cert.getEncoded()`, It is forking fine.

Comment: I was just going to write this. Good that, you have already solved it.